# CSS parent-of selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Consider this markup:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <p id="my_paragraph">Squirrels!</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Nuts</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

Is there a CSS selector that would select the first nested `div` by the fact that it contains a specific `p`? Something like `:parent-of(p#my_paragraph)`

Comment: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) **No, there is not.** (And this comes up as one of the first auto-suggested questions in the Ask Question page when you type that title.)

Comment: @BoltClock you're right, it's a duplicate. Didn't notice. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, as discussed in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). And as quoted by David Hyatt, a webkit developer:

> *With parent selectors it becomes extremely easy to accidentally cause a document-wide grovel. People can and will misuse this selector. Supporting it is giving people a whole lot of rope to hang themselves with.*